# Cannot save image intervention image. NotWritableException in Image.php line 138

Tags: php, image, laravel-5

Im trying to save a manipulated image which i will them push to s3.

My code that works **This code saves the image directly within the public folder***

```
public function store(Filesystem $filesystem)
{

    $request = Input::all();

    $validator = Validator::make($request, [
        'images' => 'image'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['upload' => 'false']);
    }

    $postId = $request['id'];

    $files = $request['file'];

    $media = [];

    $watermark = Image::make(public_path('img/watermark.png'));

    foreach($files as $file) {

        $image = Image::make($file->getRealPath());
        $image->crop(730, 547);
        $image->insert($watermark, 'center');
        $image->save($file->getClientOriginalName());

    }

}
```

What i would like to achieve is to be able to save it within a folder of it's own. Firstly what is the best place to store an image for a blog post, within the **storage** of **public** folder? But anyway when i do this:

```
$image->save('blogpost/' . $postId . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName());

// Or this

$image->save(storage_path('app/blogpost/' . $postId . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName()));
```

I get the error:

> **folder within public**
>
> NotWritableException in Image.php line 138: Can't write image data to
>   path (blogpost/146/cars/image.jpg)
>
> or
>
> **storage path**
>
> NotWritableException in Image.php line 138: Can't write image data to
>   path /code/websites/blog/storage/app/blogpost/146/image.jpg

I've tried

```
cd storage/app/  
chmod -R 755 blogpost
```

And it still wont work

Thank you for reading this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok so here is how i solved it, I made the directory first before storing,

```
Storage::disk('local')->makeDirectory('blogpost/' . $postId);
```

Once the folder is created i then go on to store the manipulated images like so:

```
$image->save(storage_path('app/blogpost/' . $postId . '/' . $imageName));
```

And then pushing the image to S3

```
$filesystem->put('blogpost/' . $postId . '/' . $imageName, file_get_contents(storage_path('app/blogpost/' . $postId . '/' . $imageName)));
```

This worked

Answer (score 8):

You can solve it by casting the `Intervation/Image` variable to a data stream using function `stream`. Then use the `Storage` Laravel facade to save the image.

```
$img = Image::make('path-to-the-image.png')->crop(...)->insert->stream('jpg', 90)
Storage::put('where_I_want_the_image_to_be_stored.jpg', $img);
```

Comment: you're a genious

Comment: i like this one than accepted answer, cleaner and let laravel do the rest

Answer (score 3):

Am improving @Amol Bansode answer.

You are getting this error because `$postId` folder does not exist in the path you specified.

You could do it like this:

```
//I suggest you store blog images in public folder
//I assume you have created this folder `public\blogpost`
$path = public_path("blogpost/{$postId}"); 

//Lets create path for post_id if it doesn't exist yet e.g `public\blogpost\23`
if(!File::exists($path)) File::makeDirectory($path, 775);

//Lets save the image
$image->save($path . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName());
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 5 needs permission to write to entire `Storage` folder so try following,

```
sudo chmod 755 -R storage
```

if `755` dont work try `777`.

Comment: Do you think this really need ?

Comment: Do this at your own risk and only on your local machine. Do not push this 777 to production!

Answer (score 2):

In my case I migrated a project from **Windows** 10 to **Parrot** (Debian-**Linux**) and I had the same problem and turned out the **slashes** were backward slashes and Linux interpret them differently. Unlike Windows, it doesn't really matter.

```
//Windows Code: 
 $image_resize->save(public_path('\storage\Features/' .'Name'.".".'png'));

//Linux Code (Working):
 $image_resize->save(public_path('storage/Features/' .'Name'.".".'jpg'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is related to Laravel but I came across from making it to work with WordPress. If somebody is coming from WordPress world, this code works (I was getting the same 'cannot write' error) and changing directory permission would not work as the library probably needs the relative path (the code below is valid for direct installation of Intervention through composer into any PHP application, not Laravel per se)-

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Intervention\Image\ImageManager;

$manager = new ImageManager(array('driver' => 'imagick'));

$image = $manager->make('PUBLIC IMAGE URL/LOCAL IMAGE PATH');
$image->crop(20, 20, 40, 40);
$image->save(__DIR__ . '/img/bar.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case:

i double check my symlinks in filesystem.php in config folder in laravel

and remove all symlink then regenerate them

`php artisan storage:link`

Answer (score 0):

in my case my fileName is not valid format for naming in windows but it worked on linux or docker

```
   $make_name = date('Y-m-d-H:i:s') . hexdec(uniqid()) . '.' . $img->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

when I remove this `date('Y-m-d-H:i:s')`  it worked as well

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same issue but **775 permission not sort it** so I changed the write permission to the folder(also sub-folders) **to 777 to get over this issue.**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).